# Convert comprehension to a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

**I have this line of code, and I'm just wondering what it would be equivalent to as a for loop.**

```
lst = [x for x in l if x !=0] + [x for x in l if x == 0]
```

Comment: Each list comprehension should be a for loop that appends to a different list. Then concatenate the lists.

Comment: The equivalent would be `sorted(l, key=lambda x: x != 0)`

Comment: A simpler equivalent would be `lst= l[:]`.

Comment: @BoarGules - That isn't equivalent

Comment: @Sayse `key=lambda x: x==0` to put zeroes last, not first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

addition of lists is concatenation so:

```
lst = []

for x in l:
    if x != 0:
        lst.append(x)
        
for x in l:
    if x == 0:
        lst.append(x)
```

more on that: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions